# First derivative positive at a point, simple properties of the first derivative

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Given a function $f:(a, b)\to \mathbb{R},\space f\in C^1$, show that $f'(x_0) =  c > 0, \space x_0\in (a,b)$ implies that there exists some $x_1\in (x_0-\delta,x_0)$ s.t. $f(x_1) < f(x_0)$ and some  $x_2\in (x_0, x_0 +  \delta)$ s.t.  $f(x_2) > f(x_0)$.

**Proof:**

We have that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = c$ meaning for  $\epsilon= c$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ s.t. for all

$x\in (x_0 -\delta, x_0 + \delta)$ we have:

$-\epsilon (x-x_0)  < f(x)-f(x_0)-c(x-x_0) < \epsilon(x-x_0)$

$\Longleftrightarrow -\epsilon (x-x_0)  + f(x_0) + c(x-x_0) < f(x) < \epsilon (x-x_0) + f(x_0) + c(x-x_0) $

So when choosing $x_1\in (x_0-\delta, x_0):$ $f(x) < f(x_0)$ and for $x_2\in(x_0, x_0 + \delta): f(x_0) < f(x)$ because $c >0$.

Is this proof correct? What would I have to  adjust when dealing with $f'(x_0) = \infty$ ?